# How to check a list in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

This is my code:

```
module Main where

import Data.Graph.Inductive
import Data.Graph.Inductive.Example

func :: Graph gr=> gr a b ->[Node]->Int-> [(Node,Int)]
func graph (x:xs) y
        |indeg graph x == 0 = (x,y+1):func (delNode x graph ) xs (y+1)

graph2:: Gr Int Int
graph2 = mkGraph (genLNodes 1 14)[(1,2,1),
                (1,3,1),    
                (3,14,1),
                (14,6,1),
                (14,7,1),
                (2,4,1),
                (2,5,1),
                (4,6,1),
                (5,7,1),
                (6,8,1),
                (7,9,1),
                (8,10,1),
                (9,11,1),
                (10,12,1),
                (11,12,1),
                (12,13,1),
                (14,13,1)]
```

Graph2 have 14 nodes and e.g (1,2,1) means, edge from node 1 to node 2 with a weight of 1.

Func takes my Graph2, topological sorting vertices and some number e.g 0.
Func checks if  inward-bound degree of the Node is equal to 0 and creates list of tuples where x is IdNode and y is increasing when indeg graph x == 0 is true. The vertex is removed

And here is my problem, I want to see if more vertices has a degree of 0 and add 1.

EDIT:

The function should act as follow:

topsort: [1,3,14,2,5,7,9,11,4,6,8,10,12,13]

1. check in-bound degree for each node in the list.
2. if degree is equal 0, add 1 to path lenght ( node 1 in-bound is equal 0 so path length= 1)
3. remove node from graph and  check in-bound degree of nodes after removing node and return to step 2.

continuing example:

after removing node 1, nodes 2 and 3 have in-bound = 0 so I add 1 to path length (path lenght = 2 for node 2 and 3 ) and I remove node 2 and 3.

Now in-bound degree =0 have 14,4,5 so I add 1 to path length (path lenght =3) and I remove these nodes and so on

I hope that the image of the graph will help.
[image: Graph]

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. It certainly doesn't seem to have much to do with “checking a list” Please describe anew what you're trying to do, best with a type signature for the function you want to define. Also: please use markdown properly: inline code snippets like `[(1,1)]` should go in backticks, like so: ``I add 1 (`[(1,1)]`)``. _And_: try to keep examples minimal. That graph of yours is certainly not as simple as it could be, for the purpose of this question.

Answer (score 1):

With lazy evaluation you can use the "tie-the-knot" method to compute the depths very declaratively:

```
minOr0 [] = 0
minOr0 ds = minimum ds

depths :: Graph gr => gr a b  -> [(Node, Int)]
depths gr =
  let pairs = [ (x, depth x) | x <- nodes gr ]
      depth x = 1 + minOr0 [ d | y <- pre gr x, let Just d = lookup y pairs ]
  in pairs

test2 = depths graph2
```

The definition between `pairs` and `depth` is circular: evaluating a tuple in `pairs` calls `depth`. Calling `depth` will look up other tuples in `pairs`. If the graph does not have any cycles the process will eventually
terminate.

Due to the way lazy evaluation works in Haskell, the calls to `depth`
are effectively memoized.